# using an xpath in selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I used firebug in Firefox to get a xpath for a link that did not have an ID assigned to it. The link is a javascript link with an image as the actual button. I'd like to be able to click this link but it's not working.

The actual xpath is '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th[1]/a/img'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

URL = 'http://example.com'

driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(url)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/‌​table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th‌​[1]/a/img"])
for link in links:
 link.click()
```

I get the following error: 
`is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id=/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th[1]/a/img because of the following error:\n[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "<unknown>"]' ; Stacktrace:`

```
<a onclick="if(typeof functionx == 'function'){functionx(document.getElement…,'liststuff','');}return false" href="#">

   <img style="border: 0px;" onmouseover="this.src='/add-hover.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='/add.gif';" alt="Add" src="/icon-add.gif"></img>

</a>
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant html code that contains the link, or provide a link to the web-site? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe sorry I can't provide the url because it's on an internal server to a company.

Comment: A guess: the `<a>` tag may have an `img` attribute instead of a nested `<img>` tag. If that's true, try changing `a/img` to `a/@img` at the end of your XPath.

Comment: @user2242044 the xpath you have is very fragile. Provide an html code so that we can see the link there.

Comment: @alecxe I added the element in the original post, but I can't add in the full html code

Comment: @unutbu I posted the actual code. I believe it's a true `<img>` tag

Comment: The XPath shown in the error message seems to be lacking a closing right bracket: `//*[@id=/html...` should probably be `//html` (since there should only be one `html` tag anyway).

Comment: modified to: `link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th[1]/a/img"])` and am now getting invalid syntax modifying original post as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having an absolute path to the element, rely on it's parent and attributes:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick and @href = "#" and img/@alt = "Add"]')
```

Comment: this executes will now code issues, but does not open the page that gets opened when I click the link manually.

Comment: @user2242044 I've updated the xpath expression, please check.

Comment: still same result. No errors but not opened link. PyCharm gives the following result `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: This worked! I accidentally removed the `link.click()` line. Thank you so much. Marking as best answer.